# How do I initialise a Date field in a Grails domain object to act as a timestamp?

Tags: grails, date, domain-object

I have a domain class which has two dates in it and I want one of them populated with the current time when a record is created for the object, like a create timestamp...

```
class Contact {
    Date initiatedDate
    Date acceptedDate
}
```

Is it sufficient just to new a `Date` object on one of them and make the other nullable until such a time as I need to fill it, sort of like this...

```
class Contact {

    static constraints = 
    {
        acceptedDate(nullable:true)
    }

    Date initiatedDate = new Date()
    Date acceptedDate
}
```

I'm experimenting, but I would like to know whether this is the right way to go about it or whether there is something more Grailsy or GORMy I should do in, say, an `init` function or by tweaking the domain object definition to have one by default, like it does an `id` and `version`.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've written should work but you can use the GORM [auto-timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) feature by simply adding a field:

```
class Contact {
    Date dateCreated
}
```

If you want to keep your own names for the fields the [same grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) also show you how to use GORM events to set fields on save or update.

HTH

Comment: that's exactly the sort of GORMy thing I was looking for, thanks